# Modify / Edit an Event on Facebook possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't see any documentation referring to the ability to edit events through the api, but I was just wondering if that's due to lack of documentation or if this is actually unavailable.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ample documentation on editing events:

- Old REST API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.edit
- Graph API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event

Note that "The application must be an admin of the event".